# Rasberry Pi Cameras v USB Cameras

Tags: usb, raspicam, picamera

I'm trying to work out what kind of cameras would best suit my Pi. The plan is to use it on moving transport for some very basic image processing. Between the RasPi and the USB cameras, which ones are sturdier? What would hold up better with continuous movement over a long period of time?

Also, does someone have experience with leaving them on for 18 hours a day, everyday?

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi camera running all the time for weeks and months in a row and never had issues. But it always depends on your software stack. If your software prefers one over the other then I'd try it the way with the least resistence to reach the MVP.

Comment: Thanks! Was it a standard Ras Pi or an industrial one?

Comment: If you refer to the HQ camera. That didn't exist monts ago.